# Combinatorics Problem about how many known

Tags: combinatorics

> On a party, there are 6 boys and a number of girls. Two of the girls
>   know exactly four boys each and the remaining girls know exactly two
>   boys each. None of the boys know more than three girls. (We assume
>   that if $A$ knows $B$, then $B$ will also know $A$.) Then, the
>   greatest possible number of girls on the party is?

This is quite difficult.

I know, in the end we will divide by $2! =2$ because of overcounting.

But how should I do this?

Comment: Please include the text of the problem in your question, rather than a _picture_ of the text. There are no formula in the text, so no reason at all why you would be unable to type it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I was sure if I typed it I would make a mistake. Hence, I thought it would be easier for others. This is from:  http://abelkonkurransen.no/problems/abel_9899_r2_prob_en.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Let us look at it as a $m\times 6$ matrix $A^{m\times6}=(a_{i,j})$ with entries in $\{0,1\}$. Here $a_{i,j}=1$ if girl $i$ knows boy $j$, and $a_{i,j}=0$ otherwise. Then the information can be interpreted as:

- $a_{1,j}+\cdots+a_{m,j}\leq 3$ for $j=1,\dots,6$
- $a_{1,1}+\cdots+a_{1,6}=4$
- $a_{2,1}+\cdots+a_{2,6}=4$
- $a_{i,1}+\cdots+a_{i,6}=2$ for $i=3,\dots,m$

From the first line we find that the sum of all entries does not exceed $18$. From the other lines it follows that the sum of all entries equals $2m+4$. So we have $2m+4\leq18$ or equivalently $m\leq7$. Is it indeed possible to find a matrix $A^{7\times6}$ that satisfies the conditions? Yes! Take e.g.:

- $a_{1,1}=a_{1,2}=a_{1,3}=a_{1,4}=1$
- $a_{2,3}=a_{2,4}=a_{2,5}=a_{2,6}=1$
- $a_{3,1}=a_{3,2}=1$
- $a_{4,3}=a_{4,4}=1$
- $a_{5,5}=a_{5,6}=1$
- $a_{6,1}=a_{6,2}=1$
- $a_{7,5}=a_{7,6}=1$

and let all other entries take value $0$.

Proved is now that $7$ is the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

7 girls. This is because we can arrange that 2 boys known by both the 4-boy girls know a third girl, and that each of the other 2 pairs of 2 boys know an extra 2 girls for each pair. 2 + 1 + 2 + 2.

I'm afraid I didn't use a very general method though, which is most of the benefit of course.